# Getting to VBA in password protected

Tags: vba, passwords, citrix

I've been tasked with updating a .xlsm file with VBA that is accessed via the Citrix Workspace application. The previous author has left the company and did not leave behind any further documentation on it.

The VBA is password protected. I've broken and readjusted VBA passwords with a hex editor before, and would gladly try that. Only thing is that the author of this current project also threw in some VBA which prevents the file from being saved as which is then password protected.

Any idea of how I can get through the save prevention VBA? Or perhaps get the file saved as a .zip to my computer?

Comment: I've downloaded a password cracker before, which got into a file for me, but not sure if the VBA was password protected on this, so have a google see what's about maybe

Comment: Disable your macros before opening the file. Then you can do whatever you want.

Comment: It is possible enough to disabe events with `Application.DisableEvents = True` for the moment  and  then fix the code i.e. remove/disable the code in the Before_Save Event.

Comment: @TimWilliams is that done only in the Trust Center Settings? I've already done that yet the code still prevents me from saving.

Comment: @Storax The VBA the code is tied to is password protected, preventing me from making any changes to it :(

Comment: If code in the workbook is running then you have not disabled macros.

Comment: @Dai Lah: You enter `Application.EnableEvents=False` in the immediate window and then no events will be fired. Even if the VBA project is password protected you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! Despite me flipping "disable macros" and ActiveX components I was still being prevented from saving the file. What I did, however, was navigate to the file's location, did a right click copy, and then just pasted it to the desktop. From there I was able to adjust the file extension to a .zip, and then cracked the password protection via the Hex editor method.